# Flask Blueprints cant override static path

Tags: python, vue.js, flask

I am trying to use Flask Blueprints to serve a multipage webapp.
Webapp structure:

Landing page html->login->Vuejs SPA

Flask structure:

```
app/
    client/
        dist/
            static/
                js/
                css/
            vue_index.html
        client.py
    main/
        main.py
    static/
        index.html
    __init__.py
```

__init_.py

```
app.register_blueprint(main_bp)
app.register_blueprint(client_bp)
```

client.py

```
client_bp = Blueprint('client', __name__,
                  url_prefix='/client',
                  static_url_path='/client/static',
                  static_folder='dist/static',
                  template_folder='dist',
                  )

@client_bp.route('/')
def client():
    dist_dir = current_app.config['DIST_DIR'] #full path to dist folder
    entry = os.path.join(dist_dir, 'vue_index.html')
    return send_file(entry)
```

vue_index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>...<script src=/static/js/index.js></script></body></html>
```

Then I run the app and redirect to host:port/client the vue_index.html is found but the .js files referred to in the file cant be found.

However when I move the js/ folder from app/client/dist/static to app/static then the vue_index.html file can locate the js code ok.

So it is evident that the blueprint is not overriding the static path of the flask app. Any idea on how to debug the static paths / fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by putting all flask static files and templates in a new dist/ folder and adding all the vuejs files into this folder eg

```
webapp/
    dist/
        js/ (vuejs files)
        css/ (vuejs and flask landing page .css)
        index.html (vuejs entry)
        other.html (flask misc webpage)
```

Then to run the app:

```
app = Flask(__name__,
        static_folder='./dist',
        template_folder='./dist',
        static_url_path='')
```

Its not ideal (I wanted to keep to vuejs files in a dist on its own and have static and template folders but just couldn't get it to work)

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `send_file` to `render_template`: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

```
from flask import render_template

# .....

@client_bp.route('/')
def client():
    return render_template('vue_index.html')
```

2. For `client_bp` use `static_url_path='static'`, because in case of `/client/static` you will create an extra nesting
3. Update your webpack config to change public URL path to your JS file with `/client` namespace:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html>...<script src=/client/static/js/index.js></script></body></html>`

Anyway I recommend you to use different non-nested folders for static files and templates

Comment: I dont have an issue with rendering the vue_index.html file I can use render_tempate or send_file. both work. The issue is getting both a static dir with vuejs files for a vue SPA (post login) and a static dir with flask files for flask templates (pre login) to both work. Currently I can get one or the other static folders to be found